# React Navigation error ```Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies'

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am having a problem with react-native-navigation packages, so I have them installed like this`npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view` But for some reason when I run `npm run android` I am getting this error for every package

````
 What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:rele
aseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :@react-native-community_masked-view.
Required by:
project :app
> No matching configuration of project :@react-native-commu
nity_masked-view was found. The consumer was configured to find a runti
me of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildT
ypeAttr' with value 'release' but:
 - None of the consumable configurations have attributes..```

Please help me
````